# Weird Windows 10 Update bug/glitch

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

How to fix this glitch?Windows update is all up to date but when I go to settings,a yellow exclamation icon which says "Updates in progress" keeps showing every now and then:

[image]

Comment: You could upvote a previous report, by me, of this behaviour: [In "All Settings" it always says "Windows Update Updates in progress" even when they are not.](https://aka.ms/AA92154) - that link will want to open Feedback Hub on your computer.

Comment: It could be just checking for updates.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  When you Windows Update what does it say exactly?  Disregard what it's saying within the Settings application for now.  Edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.